# Make followWithHeading more accurate

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-marker, mapbox-ios

We have been testing Mapbox's SDK instead of using Mapkit, and although all is clear and well documented, we already got some trouble while using

```
mapView.userTrackingMode == .followWithHeading
```

Even with Mapbox iOS SDK Examples and https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/user-tracking-mode/ it's easy to see than while using `followWithHeading` mode, the position of the user is not accurate.

But what is strange, is while we set `mapView.userTrackingMode` to `.none` then user's position is correct.

[image: Red path is correct while the blue marker is provided while using followWithHeading]
Red path is correct while the blue marker is provided while using followWithHeading is incorrect

[image: Red path is correct and blue marker is correct too while using none for userTrackingMode]
Red path is correct and blue marker is correct too while using none for userTrackingMode

Any idea ?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no. We ended to develop our own graphic engine based on Unity